# The most basic question about Feature Important or Permutation_Importance

Tags: python, feature-selection, random-forest, scikit-learn, feature-engineering

Consider the XOR gate with three inputs. The truth table will be: [image: XOR 3 Inputs Truth Table]

Now all the variables on their own are near random as far as the model is concerned. Each input 1 or 0 has a 50% chance of being classified as 1 or 0. If we are trying to use Random Forest to deduce relationships of variables which on their own should not dictate the output, how useful is feature importance? And which ones of the feature importance method will more likely provide an accurate depiction of the result?

Also, using XOR as a reference, what's the relationship in terms of data required for a random forest to create an accurate model for n features.

Comment: Random Forest won't work on this problem as stated, because no split on any single variable improves the accuracy of the estimated "Out", and RF works one variable at a time.  You need to know all three variables in order to improve accuracy beyond the basic "50%".

Comment: RF does solve it - on the third split. I wanted to use this extreme example to figure out if one can apply the same concept to a model where you don't necessarily find the correlation of features individually to outputs and if so, how do you prioritize features.

Comment: How does it make the first split?  Nothing improves accuracy, so it won't.